# Filter though an Array of Objects, Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a filter that only returns the results that are greater than a StartDate and less than an EndDate which is compared to the customDate. This Array populates a table. So far I am having no luck and have tried it 150 ways. Can someone shed a little light? Thanks.

**TypeScript:**

```
   this.evalSchedule = this.evalSchedule.filter(function(x) {
        x.filter(function (v){
           ( new Date(v.customDate) > new Date(start) && new Date(v.customDate) < new Date(end) );      
        })
      });
```

Comment: You're passing a function to filter which is supposed to return a boolean, but returns nothing and instead invokes another filter, throwing away the results?

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening! Completely throws away the results, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy for me to understand how does your data structure looks like. however there is one simple issue with your code:

```
this.evalSchedule.filter(function(x) {
  // inside filter #1
  x.filter(function (v){
    // inside filter #2
    console.log(v.customDate);
    return v.customDate > new Date(start) && new Date(v.customDate) < new Date(end) // return statement for filter #2
  })
  // in this moment x contains only elements which passed filter #2
  // now, this is problematic place
  // -> missing return statement for filter #1
  // -> it returns nothing so as default it will return undefined which will evaluate to false
  // -> filter #1 should filter out all elements of evalSchedule
});
```

For your specific data structure, code given below should work. However as @MikeMcCaughan has pointed out, we will need additional function `parseDate`, to properly handle date strings as written [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results):

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('/');
  // new Date(year, month [, day [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]);
}

this.evalSchedule.map(function(x) {
  return x.filter(function (v) {
    console.log(v.customDate);
    var customDateParsed = parseDate(v.customDate)
    return customDateParsed > parseDate(start) 
      && customDateParsed < parseDate(end);
  })
});
```

Comment: So I would say this is a two dimensional filter, inside x there is an object which contains "customDate", I would like to return x depending if custom date is within a given range. Does that make sense?

Comment: You need to define `v` in your fix.

Comment: the question is if x contains a lot of customDate objects or only one. if there is only one then its not two dimmensional array. can you show us how x is looking like? i mean it's structure.

Comment: Still won't work because you're comparing a string to a `Date` in `v.customDate > new Date(start)`. Also, won't work cross browser with the Date constructor on a string in the format shown in the OP. See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/215552) for more.

Comment: I think that types of `customDate` as well as `start` and `end` variables are not specified in a question so I assume that given variables have proper type.

Comment: @Dominik, there is a picture of the Data structure included in the question, which show the hierarchy.

Comment: Ok i see, then simply run `forEach` instead of `filter` on array `evalSchedule`
edit: or rather `evalSchedule.map ( (x) => {
  return x.filter(function (v) {
    ...
  })`
i will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ok, now when I have read that comparison statement carefully I see what you meant. Variables have to have wrong types... Thanks once again

Comment: @Dominik, Thanks for helping but this actually didn't seem to work. But for reference, I think what Mike was talking about was that the v.customDate needed to be, new Date(v.customDate) in order to compare the two. With that in place, I filtered the first set of results and then looped into the second dimension, set up a global variable and if the date fell into the range, I pushed it into that gloabal variable. After was, the global variable was assigned to my nested grid. I'll post the code in a bit. Thanks for pitching in, you helped out in the process of thinking it through!

Comment: I believe that things mentioned by Mike are already in my answer. That is parsing `string` `customeDate` manualy and then putting it into `Date` constructor. I think that there is no need for global variablels and other kind of stuff since its quite easy task to solve. don't you mind to elaborate on what is not working with proposed solution? :)

Comment: please note that map function does not modify source array so to acces the result of operation you should assign it to (possibly new) variable like this: `let modifiedEvalSchedule = this.evalSchedule.map(...)`. Sorry that I haven't mentioned it in the answer